# MVC 5 Submit form in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I want submit form but when i click button submit then nothing happens. Help me!
p/s: I'm sorry so you can't understand because i poor English.

This is my code in Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate")] Student student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Students.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

Next code in Javascript

```
<script>
        var inputs = document.forms['register'].getElementsByTagName('input');
        var run_onchange = false;
        var errors = false;
        function valid() {
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                var value = inputs[i].value;
                var id = inputs[i].getAttribute('id');
                var dateReg = /^\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/;

                var span = document.createElement('span');

                var p = inputs[i].parentNode;
                if (p.lastChild.nodeName == 'SPAN') { p.removeChild(p.lastChild); }


                if (value == '') {
                    span.innerHTML = 'Required Information';
                }
                else {
                    if (id == 'LastName' || id == 'FirstMidName') {
                        if (value.length == 1) { span.innerHTML = 'Min 2 character! Re-type'; }
                    }

                    if (id == 'EnrollmentDate')
                        if (dateReg.test(value) == false) {
                            { span.innerHTML = 'EnrollmentDate invalid! Re-type'; }
                        }
                }

                if (span.innerHTML != '') {
                    inputs[i].parentNode.appendChild(span);
                    errors = true;
                    run_onchange = true;
                    inputs[i].style.border = '1px solid #c6807b';
                    inputs[i].style.background = '#fffcf9';
                }
            }

            if (errors == false) {
                document.getElementById("register").submit();
            }
                return !errors;  
        }
            var register = document.getElementById('submit_button');
            register.onclick = function () {
                return valid();
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                var id = inputs[i].getAttribute('id');
                inputs[i].onchange = function () {
                    if (run_onchange == true) {
                        this.style.border = '1px solid #999';
                        this.style.background = '#fff';
                        valid();
                    }                   
                }
            }

    </script>
```

End code View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { name = "register", id = "register" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstMidName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstMidName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_button" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Please do not use the `jQuery` tag unless you use/want jQuery. Where is your script in the page? At the end? It is not in an onload handler.

Comment: You have made your button `<input type="button" ...>` which does not submit a form. Change it to `<input type="submit" ...>` Then go to the MVC site and learn the basics of validation in MVC using validation attributes on your properties, using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in your view and using unobtrusive client side validation - and then delete that awful script :)

Comment: Ok! I delete tag jQuery. My script to just below my code View inside @section Script { }

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank but i newbier learn javascript and i don't want to use @@Html.ValidationMessageFor() in my code. I want check forn by javascript

Comment: Your action is `[HttpPost]` but your form's `FormMethod` is `FormMethod.Get` so won't hit the post action.  Try changing the form to `@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post,...`.

Comment: The question appears to be about why a `.submit()` call doesn't submit, yet there's large amounts of js that isn't relevant to the question.  Try cutting some of it out temporarily (eg assume the form is valid and skip straight to the "if (errors==false)" code (remove all the other code)).  Then update the question.  See here for more info:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried chaging the form to `@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post,..)` but it nothing happens when I submit.